# Vertically align button text?

Tags: html, ios, css, font-face

I have the following code to display text on a generic button: https://jsfiddle.net/6ogo4bqr/

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Log In" class="btn1" />
<br />
<input id="Button2" type="button" value="Log In" class="btn2" />
<br />
<div id="Button3" class="btn3">Log In</div>
```

It works fine on Firefox but on an iPad the button text appears more towards the top of the button (though it's OK when it uses `Helvetica` or `Arial`):

[image: Screenshot]

How can I get the text to align vertically on iOS (BTW I couldn't get JSFiddle to use @font-face)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found that the particular font file I used was corrupt. It all worked ok when I replaced the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try and remove the top and bottom padding of the text and adding a `line-height` instead.

Comment: Thanks - I tried that but it didn't work - as per other comment on line-height

Answer (score 0):

```
#selector{
  /*set both top and bottom padding with same values */
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried that but it didn't work. Note that my original JSFiddle does in fact work when the font is Helvetica and not FuturaMaxiBold